# starting an Android Service on TCP connection attempt

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, server

Android can kill a process at any time, it is only possible to change the likelihood that a process will be killed by doing things such as making it foreground.  So it seems to me that servers that sit on a TCP port waiting for a connection are problematic, although I do see apps that do this.  Is there some mechanism these servers use to make sure that they are always available to answer requests?  Periodic intents to start the process would drain battery power too quick.  Starting with the sticky bit isn't foolproof in making sure a service gets restarted after being killed, and neither is foregrounding.  That leaves me thinking that perhaps there might be some way to request an Intent when a particular TCP port receives a SYN request on.  Obviously the service would have to be started and somehow open the port before an ACK was returned or else the initial connection attempt would fail and have to be retried.

Is there something like this going on or available?

Comment: Probably not.  Remember that Android is designed primarily to sit on a mobile network that won't route incoming connections anyway. You might be able to use google cloud messaging to wake it up though.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Interesting. So how does GCM insure that incoming messages from the server are always turned into Intents?  Seems like that is the functionality that I need.

Comment: A combination of intitiating a connection and being "special" in the eyes of the operating system and power management (ie, "network tickle").

Comment: @ChrisStratton So you are saying it's built into Android to talk directly to Google's servers, and if I want to implement the exact same functionality to talk to my server, I'm out of luck?